# How to align the text on the top of the div with Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a code using Tailwind here:

```
       <div className="flex flex-row mt-2">
            <div className="flex-none w-12 h-12">
                <Avatar>
                    <AvatarImage
                        src="https://github.com/shadcn.png"
                        alt="@shadcn"
                    />
                    <AvatarFallback>CN</AvatarFallback>
                </Avatar>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-1 flex-col">
                <div className="flex-none grid grid-cols-2">
                    <div className="font-semibold ">userid</div>
                    <div className="text-right">2w</div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex-1 text-pretty break-all mt-1">
                    sometext here sometext here sometext here sometext here
                    sometext here sometext here sometext here sometext here
                    sometext here sometext here sometext here sometext here
                    sometext here sometext here sometext here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However, I'm not able to align the top of the text to the top of the avatar image, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhrgz.png).

Basically I want the top of the `userid` touch the top boarder, any adive would be great, thanks!

tried tailwind align item top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use line-height to change the height of text. In tailwind, you can use `leading-[5px]`
[image: Illustration]

```
    <div className="flex flex-row mt-2 w-1/2">
        <div className="flex-none w-12 h-12">
          <div>
            <img src="https://github.com/shadcn.png" alt="@shadcn" />
            <!-- <AvatarFallback>CN</AvatarFallback> -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 flex-col">
          <div className="flex-none grid grid-cols-2 leading-[5px]">
            <div className="font-semibold ">userid</div>
            <div className="text-right">2w</div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex-1 text-pretty break-all mt-1">
            sometext here sometext here sometext here sometext here sometext here sometext
            here sometext here sometext here sometext here sometext here sometext here
            sometext here sometext here sometext here sometext here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you accept my answer! That will help me a lot